I make a custom entity with dbx, and creat a com wrapper ,but some errors apper at run time
I want to implements some functionality: the plugin runs in AutoCAD , create a cunstom entity , and  show it's properties in OPM, i found a reference file(Tutorial on COM Services for Custom Objects) online.
according to this file, first i create a ObjectDBX project——MyRings, and creat a cunstom entity named  AsdkRings,second I creat a ObjectARX——RingsWrappe used to wrapper the AsdkRings with COM.Compile the program and the it create two file, AsdkMyRings.dbx and AsdkRingsWrapper.arx.
I load AsdkMyRings.dbx after opening AutoCAD , then load AsdkRingsWrapper.arx, when i open the VBAIDE, and enter the following code.
Public Sub test()
    'Create a Rings object
    Dim o As Rings
    Set o = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCustomObject("AsdkRings")
    'Set object's radius, normal, center and number of rings
    o.Radius = 5
    Dim n(0 To 2) As Double
    n(2) = 1
    o.Normal = n
    Dim c(0 To 2) As Double
    o.Center = c
    o.Rings = 4
End Sub

then reference the COM wrapper, and run, some error happen, like the following picture show, translate to English is "runtime error: 428, ActiveX component can't creat object", i can't find why the error happened ,i make the plugin based on the reference file ,
enter image description here
the environment i used:
AutoCAD 2024
VS2019
objectarx wizard 2024
i've searched online and there is less information about it, i want to know why cause this error,and solve this problem.
